# Linux Command Shell: OverWriting Issue

Tags: html, linux, shell, cp, mv

I have been given the assignment to create a webpage with a figlet text in a `<pre>` block as a "header", a picture in the middle, and a custom cowsay image at the bottom in another `<pre>` block as the "footer". We are using a remote server for the class that I am using putty to connect up to and use the linux shell.

I can't figure out a way to export my figlet text or cowsay image into the file I created without it overwriting everything else already in the file.

This is really the first time I've done anything html or linux command line related so I'm quite lost. Any and all help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could edit the file with nano from linux command line, then you can paste with right-click.
Or probably better would be to update the file on your local computer (so you have a backup / working copy) and then upload with SFTP.

Comment: Mr. Joe, could you explain the process of uploading with SFTP using the Linux shell? Also, I was under the impression from my lecture/ notes that nano is only used for creating files, it can also be used to edit them?

Comment: yes i use nano to edit all the time.  For SFTP you would get a program such as winSCP and use SFTP with the same SSH login credentials that you use in putty. https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Comment: Wow. I have been looking up other commands and wondering why there wasn't something simple to edit with like nano for 2 hours. 'vi' is evil. Anyhow, about the SFTP upload, what commands would I use to go about that?

Comment: i assume you're working on windows or mac?  Download winscp and run it, choose SFTP and it's a visual drag and drop from there.  Or actually if you're on mac, you can run sftp from command line, but then yeah you'd need to know the command is "put FILENAME"

Comment: a few nano shortcuts to get you started:   
ctrl + e - move cursor to end of line,  
ctrl + w - search the file for text,
shift + insert - paste from your clipboard, 
ctrl + x - exit and press y to save, or choose n to not save...

Comment: awww its shift insert, i was hitting ctr v time after time. Thanks!

Comment: yeah ctrl + v is page down, i do it out of habit by mistake all the time too, ctrl + y to go back up

Comment: So when I used shift insert, it still overwrote everything I had in the file before hand, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: are you sure it didn't just push it down?  shift + insert shouldn't overwrite anything in nano as far as i know.  after you save out with nano, you can use "more FILENAME" to view the text contents of the file from command line.

Comment: Aww sorry man, I just didn't scroll down. Thanks for all the help sir, I couldn't have done this without it. God Bless!